# Connecting a JavaEE 7 web application with Oracle database 10g

Tags: database, oracle, web-applications, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

What is the best approach for connecting a Java EE 7 web application to an Oracle Database using database's credentials?

I've only used persistence units that consume a *jdbc-resource* for binding a web service and an Oracle DB, like this:

```
<property name="serverName" value="[server-name]"/>
<property name="portNumber" value="1521"/>
<property name="databaseName" value="[database-name]"/>
<property name="User" value="[user-name]"/>
<property name="Password" value="[password]"/>
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@[server-name]:1521:[database-name]"/>
```

But now, I need login with different credentials based on database's user. It's necessary to use a session object provided by Java EE 7 API?

My toolset:

- Oracle Database 10g
- JavaEE 7
- JavaSE 8
- ojdbc7.jar
- GlassFish 4

Comment: Do you intend to create a database connection per user?

Comment: @aribeiro Yes. per database user